# Folland's real analysis, proposition 4.13, association between definition of neighborhood and a distance

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

> **C(X)**: The space of all complex-valued continuous functions on $X$.
> **BC(X)**: The space of all complex-valued bounded and continuous functions on $X$.

In the following proposition, Folland proves $C(X)$ is complete. But I'm confused about the part highlighted in red:

[image]

Previously our definition of "neighborhood" and "continuous at $x$" are

> **Neighborhood**: $X$ is a topological space, $A$ is a neighborhood of $x\in X$ or $E\subset X$ if $x\in A^{\mathrm{o}}$ or $E\subset A^{\mathrm{o}}$.
>
> **Continuous at $x$**: $X$ is a topological space, $x\in X$. $f$ is continuous at $x$ if
> for any neighborhood $V$ of $f(x)$, there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ s.t. $f(U)\subset V$.

My question is:

In a topological space, I never observe the book associate the definition of a neighborhood with a "distance" or "metric." However, the highlighted part seems to indicate that "the distance between two points of a neighborhood is upper bounded." I probably missed something obvious, but why does it say so?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It's the definition of continuous function. Preimage of open set is open.

Comment: You’re confusing domain and range. $X$ is a topological space and $U$ is an open set in it. Distance applies only to the values of the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functions $f_n$ are complex-valued, and the topology of the complex numbers is induced by the usual metric $d(z,w) = |z-w|$. Using your notation for a continuous function, the neighborhood $V$ here in the codomain is the open ball $V = \{z \in \mathbb C\ \mid |z - f(x)| < \epsilon/3\}$.